# Find the angle of perspective tilting from matrix by getPerspectiveTransform ?

Tags: python, opencv3.0, perspective

I want to be able to compute the tilting angle on an object in consecutive frames. I have acquired the four corners that defined this object and can use the getPerspective + warpPerspective to correct perspective tilting.

But how do I get the angle between normal and tilted object ? I figure since the warpMatrix is used to correct the perspective tilt, it should contains these angle information. How do I mathematically compute the tilting angle from warpMatrix ?